# How to Formalize Noise Protocol Messages

Tags: diffie-hellman, noise-protocol

I try to understand the messages of the [Noise Protocol Framework](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/). The handshakes are based on Diffie-Hellmann key exchange.
This is an example for a handshake pattern:

```
-> e
<- e, ee, s, es
```

I try to formalize the handshake with mathematical descriptions.
For example the mathematical description of the first message is:
[image]. Where [image] is a generator and [image] is the private ephemeral key of the sender.
But I don't understand how the values **ee** and **es** are calculated.
How can these patterns be descriebed mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

**ee** and **es** aren't values, they're function invocations.

**ee** denotes the use of a Diffie-Hellman key exchange using two **e**phemeral keys, **es** denotes the use of a Diffie-Hellman key exchange using an **e**phemeral key and a **s**tatic key. The first letter is the initiator, the second is the responder.

So it's just $ee = DH(e, re)$, $es=DH(e,rs)$, $se = DH(s, re)$, $ss = DH(s, rs)$, where $DH(i,r)$ is the Diffie-Hellman exchange function applied to the $i$nitiator's key and the $r$espoder's key.